# Getting 'pip' is not recognized

Tags: python, pip, module

What to do if i'm not able to install module in python?
I even download pip module but it's still not able to download module using pip.py
I even used some to cmnds to download pip module in VS CODE .Getting the same issue in IDLE .

Comment: Are you in windows, linux or Mac? If your in Windows, pip comes with python's installation automatically. Open a new terminal (cmd or pwsh) and run python directly from the installation path as `.\python.exe -m pip install requests`. If you're on linux you need `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling it completely from control panel and reinstalling maybe it should work